# Prevent Spring from dropping tables and instead drop the schema only

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using Postgres and Spring Boot JPA and would like specific application instances to cleanly

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create-drop`

their respective schemas (each instance has its own schemaName).

I.E. on startup (prior to other db statements) and shutdown

```
"drop schema [schemaName] if exists cascade"
```

and then (only on startup)

```
 "create schema [schemaName] if not exists"
```

should be issued.

This seems to work after some fiddeling, however, Spring/Hibernate also issues

```
"drop table[schemaName.tableName] if exists cascade"
```

Since this [Postgres issue](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20130125132651.GS21914%40momjian.us) still does not seem to be fixed, I'm getting misleading warnings

```
"o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper: schema "schemaName" does not exist, skipping"
```

on startup and I don't want to silence the whole logger.

How do I tell Spring/Hibernate not to issue those delete table statements (or what are other ways to prevent this issue from happening)? I prefer not to use SQL-Init scripts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Skipping creation of a specific table [Spring] [Hibernate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63649640/skipping-creation-of-a-specific-table-spring-hibernate)

I came up with this solution:

```
class PreventDropTablesSchemaFilter : DefaultSchemaFilterProvider() {

    override fun getDropFilter() = INSTANCE

    val INSTANCE = object : DefaultSchemaFilter() {
        override fun includeTable(table: Table) = false
    }
}
```

and then

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.schema_filter_provider: PreventDropTablesSchemaFilter
```